# Resident Evil S.T.A.R.S

Tags: video-games, zombie, resident-evil

What are the positions in the S.T.A.R.S Team and what do they mean?

For example Jill Valentine was the breaking and entering specialist.

Comment: http://residentevil.wikia.com/Special_Tactics_and_Rescue_Service - All the roles are listed here.

Comment: B&E generally stands for "Breaking and Entering". I'm unaware of any other usage.

Comment: You may want to specify if this is the movie or game universes. IIRC the two teams are quite different according to which you prefer.

Comment: so jill is a bomb expert and lock expert?

Comment: @LiamBrown More like, "knock knock,Police!" Expert

Comment: oh you mean a breacher?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Resident:  Evil wiki](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Tactics_and_Rescue_Service#Unit_positions):

> Mission Leader (field commander of the team)
> Pointman (field scouting and reconnaissance)
> Backup Man (provides assistance to the Pointman)
> Omni Man (in charge of vehicle and weapon maintenance)
> Rear Security (in charge of establishing contact between the headquarters and the helicopter, as well as treating injured teammates).

Examples of duties, from the same source:

#### Backup Man:

- Communications expert (Richard Aiken)
- Weapons supervisor (Barry Burton)

#### Rear-security:

- Chemicals expert (Rebecca Chambers)
- Medic (Rebecca Chambers)
- Pilot (Edward Dewey, Brad Vickers)
- Computer Specialist (Brad Vickers)
- Breaking and Entering Specialist (Jill Valetine)

#### Omni Man:

- Maintenance supervisor (Joseph Frost)
- Maintenance (Forest Speyer)
- Sharpshooter (Forest Speyer)

#### Team Captain:

- Bravo leader (Enrico Marini)
- Division leader (Albert Wesker)

#### Pointman:

- Chemist (Kenneth Sullivan)
- Sharpshooter (Chris Redfield)
- Copilot  (Chris Redfield)